# Wordpress Custom Taxonomy Filter

Tags: php, wordpress, search, filter, custom-taxonomy

I am trying to create a product filter that works something like this:

http://www.permco.com/

I have got it to a point that i have called in the taxonmoies and put them in drop downs.

```
$prodtype = array(
   'show_option_all'    => '',
   'show_option_none'   => '',
   'orderby'            => 'ID', 
   'order'              => 'ASC',
   'show_count'         => 0,
   'hide_empty'         => 1, 
   'child_of'           => 0,
   'exclude'            => '',
   'echo'               => 1,
   'selected'           => 0,
   'hierarchical'       => 0, 
   'name'               => 'cat',
   'id'                 => '',
   'class'              => 'postform',
   'depth'              => 0,
   'tab_index'          => 0,
   'taxonomy'           => 'product-types',
   'hide_if_empty'      => false,
); 
$displacement = array(
   'show_option_all'    => '',
   'show_option_none'   => '',
   'orderby'            => 'ID', 
   'order'              => 'ASC',
   'show_count'         => 0,
   'hide_empty'         => 1, 
   'child_of'           => 0,
   'exclude'            => '',
   'echo'               => 1,
   'selected'           => 0,
   'hierarchical'       => 0, 
   'name'               => 'cat',
   'id'                 => '',
   'class'              => 'postform',
   'depth'              => 0,
   'tab_index'          => 0,
   'taxonomy'           => 'displacement',
   'hide_if_empty'      => false,
 ); 

<form>
<b><?php _e('Product Type'); ?></b><br/>
<?php wp_dropdown_categories($prodtype); ?>
<br/>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
var dropdown = document.getElementById("cat");
function onCatChange() {
    if ( dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value > 0 ) {
        location.href = "<?php echo get_option('home');
?>/?cat="+dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
    }
}
dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;
--></script>
<b><?php _e('Displacement'); ?></b><br/>
<?php wp_dropdown_categories($displacement); ?>
<br/>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
var dropdown = document.getElementById("cat");
function onCatChange() {
    if ( dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value > 0 ) {
        location.href = "<?php echo get_option('home');
 ?>/?cat="+dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
    }
 }
dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;
--></script>
```

My issue is that I can't then get the dropdowns to refresh the page and reload the products automatically like they do on the example website.

So what i would like it to do is once the user has selected an item from the dropdown the products refresh and load up ones matching that criteria, then when they select an option from the second dropdown i want the products to automatically filter through and show only products that match both those selections.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It can done via using jQuery. In the website you mentioned above they have implemented the same trick which can be found in the fucntions file..

see below: You can implement something along this path to get desired results.

Code from ref. Site:

`e.filterChange = {init: function () {
        if (!jQuery.browser.mobile) {
            $("#filter_submit").hide();
            $(".filterNote").show();
            $("#form_filter .dk_options a").live($.browser.msie || $.browser.safari ? "mousedown" : "click", function (e) {
                $parent = $(this).closest(".dk_container");
                $curValue = $parent.find(".dk_label");
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $("#form_filter").submit()
                }, 500)
            })
        }
    }};`

Answer (score 0):

Example to create a [Wordpress taxonomy filter with AJAX.](https://convertintowordpress.com/wordpress-multiple-taxonomy-filter-ajax/) . It's an example of taxonomy filter with woocommerce products.